# CPU (or IC) recommendation for independent use (without PC components) for Speech recognition and computer vision over Wifi

Tags: processor, memory, signal-processing, brain-computer-interface

I have been doing some hands on in AI and Computer Vision lately (using OpenNLP, OpenCV, etc). All these experiments were done on my PC (Intel dual core 8GB DDR2). But, now I want to use some processing unit only for AI purposes (no need of monitor, keyboard, mouse etc.). I am planning to use this processor wirelessly connected with network of webcams and microphones throughout my house (let's see a network of 4-5 cameras and microphone) in a star topology with CPU/IC as central server and cameras as nodes.

I am not good with hardware requirements and compatibility of various parts. So, can someone recommend any minimalist required CPU configuration or any IC, which can get this job done. And, what other components will be needed along with CPU/IC (for e.g motherboard)? Or at least point me in the direction where I can find my answers? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the bitrate on the camera feeds individually, and what kind of processing/storage, if any are you doing on these feeds? Also, what is the current strain on your system when doing the work?

Comment: I'd also like to add, do you have any sort of budget?

Comment: @AdamWykes Bitrate would typically be around 600-800kbps. This feed will be routed to the central server (CPU /IC) which will then stream it on my android phone via internet. Also, I want to do some speech recognition and image recognition (not to a great detail). Also I am not planning to store video feeds. just streaming it. My current problem is, my laptop is needed when I want to run this system.

Comment: I want to make it self-dependent in terms of hardware and processing, and I don't want to invest in another full-fledged laptop or PC system (also want to keep it to small size like wifi router or similar). That's why I am looking for minimilist processing unit without much compromising on processing power.

Comment: @ElBromista I am looking something within 150 $. But, can extend budget a bit. Also, this budget only includes processor/IC and SSD / SD card for memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I recommend the **[ASRock J3710-ITX Mini ITX Pentium J3710 Motherboard](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-ASRock-Rack-J3160-ITX-Intel-Celeron-J3160-DDR3-SATA3-USB3-0-A-V-GbE-/381706767471?_trksid=p2352135.m2548.l4275)**. This motherboard features an integrated quad core CPU that might provide the performance you're looking for - it's very difficult to say because you haven't given us a whole lot of information about the programs/dev environments you're using, but anyway it's significantly faster than your current CPU. Outfit this with at least 8gb RAM and a good SSD if you'll be caching any of that A/V data to disk.

Given that you're using OpenCV, it might be worth it to get an Athlon 5370 and board instead, as this would allow you to use the relatively powerful AMD GPU on that 5370 to accelerate your OpenCV work via OpenCL.